# Replace all the text occurrences in the DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I ma trying to write a chrome extension to replace all the specific occurrences of the text in a web page with a custom text.

I found similar questions in SO and tried the following solution but it doesn't seem to work.

```
   config.text_config = [
        {
            src: "Lorem ipsum",
            target: "live long and prosper"
        }
    ]
   config.text_config.forEach(function (obj) {

        $('*').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(obj.src, 'REPLACEMENT_TEXT');
            $(this).text(text);
        })

    });
```

Can anyone lend me a hand here?

Comment: _"it doesn't seem to work"_ Can include stacksnippets at Question to demonstrate ?

Comment: Well, I am working on a chrome extension. How can I add snippets? :/

Comment: Requirement _"to replace all the specific occurrences of the text in a web page with a custom text."_ should return same results whether called within a chrome extension or not called within a chrome extension. Can provide example of html tried to change that did not return expected results using `js` at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like, in order to be sure to replace text for all nodes:

```js
$(function () {
  $.fn.getTextNodes = function(contentText) {
    return $(this).find(":not(iframe)").addBack().contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf(contentText) != -1;
    });
  };
  var config = {}
  config.text_config = [
    {
      src: "Lorem ipsum",
      target: "live long and prosper"
    }
  ];
  config.text_config.forEach(function (obj) {
    var re = new RegExp(obj.src, 'g');
    $('*').getTextNodes(obj.src).each(function(item, element) {
      this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(re, 'REPLACEMENT_TEXT');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<div id="Message area">
    <div class="selected-div">
        Operation Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 1
    </div>
    <div class="selected-div">
        Operation Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 2
    </div>
    <div class="selected-div">
        Operation Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 3
    </div>
    <div class="selected-div">
        Operation Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well I need to search the entire DOM.

Comment: @Fawzan I updated my answer, in order to let you handle all the elements in the dom, also the element not handled from jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the code doesn't consider the case where 'Lorem ipsum' occurs twice in a div. eg `Operation Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 1`