# what is the best way to replace all occurrence of words on html page based on a map?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension to replace a few words on a webpage.
For example, I have a map like the one below.

```
let x = {
    "apple": "alice",
    "banana": "barney"
};
```

For every occurrence of one of the keys in the map, I would like to replace it with the corresponding value from the map. What is the efficient way to do this in javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "best" and "efficient"?

Comment: See this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556960/replace-all-the-text-occurrences-in-the-dom-with-jquery

Comment: I mean, do I replace the words one at a time, or is there some regex solution? and also ensure that there are no major side effects in the behavior of the page.

Comment: Replace `.textContent` of individual elements in a loop instead of replacing entire HTML as a string.

Comment: The issue is with things like `<a href="alice.html">` or `<b>A</b>lice`

Answer (score 0):

This method assumes you want to scan/modify all occuring OUTPUTED words with alternative words from an entire document loaded in an iframe.

```
const OldWords=['apple','alice','banana','barney'];

const NewWords=['fdg','tyu','xcv','jqw'];


var N=FrameID.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('*'), S='', x=0;  

for(var i=0; i<N.length; i++){

 S=N[i].innerText;

 if(S!==''){

  for(x=0; x<OldWords.length; x++){

   if(S.indexOf(OldWords[x])>-1){

    N[i].innerText=N[i].innerText.replace(new RegExp(OldWords[x],'g'),NewWords[x]);

   }

  }

 }

}
```

NB: To use this code change FrameID to your iframe's ID, and edit the two arrays as required.

PS: I have question for you... why do you want to do this? I can't think why this would be useful.

Comment: There was an extension "millennials to snake people" that did this. That one was for comedic effect. But, there are other, more useful and practical applications such as filtering for children or people who don't want to get offended browsing the web. Also by replacing complex words with easier to understand synonyms would make scientific articles a little easier to read.

Comment: Ah OK, a naughty word filter for kids... I'll add that to my browser! :)